# rails: validates_format_of use regex to limit line of numbers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

I'm try to use **regex** to limit line of numbers, I have tried this, does not work like  what I thought.

I have a `Product` model has only `info` attribute, and it has one validation

```
validates_format_of :info, with: /(.*\n){,3}
```

in rails console

```
> product = Product.new
> product.info = <<-INFO
">   line one  
">   line two
">   line three
">   line four
"> INFO
> product.valid? 
=> true
```

I thought this should return `false`, as `info` has more than **3** line of numbers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use custom validation to a check number of lines in a string. In my opinion it provides better readability than using a regexp.

```
validate :info_cannot_have_many_lines
def info_cannot_have_many_lines
  error << 'Info can not have more than 3 lines' if info.lines.count > 3
end
```

If you want to stick with a Regexp:

```
/\A(.*(\r\n|\r|\n)){,3}\z/
```

You need to use the anchors: \A (beginning of the string) and \z (end of the string)

Edit: I guess it is better to use `(\r\n|\r|\n)` instead of just `\n`, so it matches for other OS too.

Comment: I known this，but I want to try regex

Comment: @DiodonHystrix Just a note, You cannot use or `|` inside `[ ]` in your regex. `[ ]` will match any single character in the set including `|`. Consider changing it to `( )`